# UIButton will not disable when referenced from IBOutlet but does when referenced from IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have checked several times to ensure that my connections are correct in IB.

```
// This does not work
UIButton *additionButton = [self.gameShopCoinButtonCollection objectAtIndex:0];
additionButton.enabled = NO;

// This does work
-(IBAction)gameShopBuyButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Does `[self.gameShopCoinButtonCollection objectAtIndex:0];`return not `nil` object?

Comment: It returns nil, but it shows that it is connected in IB.

Comment: Try to use direct reference rather then collection. It should save your time.

Comment: Did the direct reference and it is still nil

Comment: property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gameButtonAdditionCoins; synthesize gameButtonAdditionCoins = _gameButtonAdditionCoins; Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry dumb mistake, I was referencing the outlet before the xib was loaded.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To disable -

```
additionButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee the order of items in an IBOutletCollection. You'll need to get a direct reference to the button and disable it that way.